# PhpStorm - How to detect PHP error "Non-static method should not be called statically"?

Tags: php, phpstorm, code-inspection, phpmd, phpcodesniffer

With PHP, static method can be used in both static method and non-static method, and non-static method can only used in non-static method. That's why calling a dynamic method statically generates the `E_STRICT` error.

For example:

```
<?php

class Example
{
    public function foo() {
        return "Foo";
    }

    public static function bar() {
        return "Bar";
    }
}

$ex = new Example();

// Non-static call
echo $ex->bar();

// Static call on a non-static method
// PHP Error "Strict standards: Non-static method should not be called statically"
// ERROR NOT DETECTED BY PHPSTORM!
echo Example::foo();
```

The last line will generated this PHP error (it's logic):
[image]

I am currently working on a large PHP application that calls, in some PHP files, non-static methods statically.  It was not a problem with an very old version of PHP but we have decided to migrate to the latest PHP version.

Manually check all the project files to identify this bad syntax will be too long (+ 1000 files)!

**The built-in code inspection features of PhpStorm doesn't detect this type of error within the analyzed source code. Why? Should I configure something? How?**

Below, my PHP code inspection configuration in PhpStorm:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine: http://postimg.org/image/y82q2zzuj/  1) Try `Code | Inspect Code...` on this file; 2) or even `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE.

Comment: To run this inspection only -- use `Code | Run Inspection by Name...` (it's faster that doing full `Inspect Code` for each file).

Comment: I think that `Invalidate Caches` and a full restart of PhpStorm did the trick. Inspection of this specific error seems to be buggy, I don't understand why (totally OK with other PHP errors/warnings). @LazyOne : in any case, thanks! http://s28.postimg.org/gr2aoquyl/phpstorm_php_inspection_3.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That inspection works fine here ([proof](http://postimg.org/image/y82q2zzuj/)).

1. Please try `Code | Inspect Code...` on this file -- it will force re-analysing of this file from scratch. Any better?
2. If nothing -- please do `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE

---

P.S.
If you are interested of **running this inspection only on whole project** -- use `Code | Run Inspection by Name...`  -- it's much faster that doing full `Inspect Code` for each file.

Comment: I think that `Invalidate Caches` and a full restart of PhpStorm did the trick. Inspection of this specific error seems to be buggy, I don't understand why (totally OK with other PHP errors/warnings). @LazyOne : in any case, thanks! http://s28.postimg.org/gr2aoquyl/phpstorm_php_inspection_3.png

Answer (score 1):

Static code analysis may hint some potential errors. It never guarantees there are no errors, and one really shouldn't rely on it.

As a practical advice, you can search for all static calls with something like

```
grep -roh "\w\+::.\+\?("
```

and analyse the list yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Change the error reporting in your php.ini file

error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED